# Solving Polynomial wave equation of the second degree

Tags: calculus

How to solve this wave equation:

$$ay^2\psi+by\psi+\frac {d^2\psi}{dx^2}=0$$
here $c=\frac {d^2\psi}{dx^2}$
where, the equation is a quadratic equation (a univariate polynomial equation of the second degree).
example:
$ay^2+by+c=0,$

$y=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},$

the problem is that here there are two wave functions after $y^2$ and $y$:

$ay^2\psi+by\psi+c=0,$

thats why i dont know how to solve it.

**Remark:** Is this solution true?

$$(y+\frac {b}{2a})^2\psi=\frac {(b^2\psi-4ac)}{4a^2},$$
to solve this i take the wave function under the radical.
$$y\sqrt {\psi}=\frac{-b\sqrt {\psi}\pm\sqrt{b^2\psi-4ac}}{2a}$$

isn't it wrong to take take the wave function under the radical$\sqrt {\psi}$ ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Solving wave equation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46306/solving-wave-equation).

Comment: Is $y$ a constant? a function of $x$? Is $\psi$ just a function of one variable, $x$? Are you trying to solve for $y$? or for $\psi$?

Comment: @m0nhawk  thats me my physics page was hacked i still dont know why!.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson just $\psi(x)$

Comment: @m0nhawk what you think,
is it true?

Comment: Neo, you are a person of few words, far too few for me to understand how your reply to my comment engages with all my concerns.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  omm, ok just tell me, can i square the wave function $\sqrt {\psi}$?

Comment: I might be able to answer that if I knew the answers to the questions you have ignored.

Comment: i didnt ingnored anything or anyone!!!
Is y a constant? i dont know!, but y is not a function. 
 Is $\psi$ just a function of one
variable, x ? yes
im trying to
solve for y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sn't it wrong to take take the wave function under the radical? no, it is not wrong.
for example:
$\psi=A\sin kx$
$\sqrt {\psi}=\sqrt {A\sin kx}$

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to solve $$a\psi y^2+b\psi y+{d^2\psi\over dx^2}=0$$ for $y$, where $a,b$ are constants, $a\ne0$, and $\psi$ is a function of $x$, then I can't see any reason for not using the quadratic formula, getting $$y={-b\psi\pm\sqrt{b^2\psi^2-4a\psi\psi''}\over2a\psi}$$ where I have written $\psi''$ for ${d^2\psi\over dx^2}$. One must avoid those $x$ for which $\psi(x)=0$.